# ContentMD5 Amazon S3 Upload Bad Digest

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, character-encoding, md5

I am able to upload files to S3, however when passing the ContentMD5 param, I always get the error:

```
{ [BadDigest: The Content-MD5 you specified did not match what we received.]
  message: 'The Content-MD5 you specified did not match what we received.',
  code: 'BadDigest',
  time: Mon Jun 15 2015 17:47:19 GMT-0400 (EDT),
  statusCode: 400,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 30 }
```

Edit: Added link
Now the [docs from amazon](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html) say:

```
   The output of the MD5 algorithm is a 128 bit digest.  When viewed in
   network byte order (big-endian order), this yields a sequence of 16
   octets of binary data.  These 16 octets are then encoded according to
   the base64 algorithm in order to obtain the value that is placed in
   the Content-MD5 field.  Thus, if the application of the MD5 algorithm
   over the raw data of a MIME entity results in a digest having the
   (unlikely) value of "Check Integrity!", then that MIME entity's
   header could contain the field
```

So it would appear that with a file that returns this md5,

```
computer:NU isaac$ md5 ~/Desktop/mediumFile.dat 
MD5 (/Users/isaac/Desktop/mediumFile.dat) = ce377789add2698f68d4cb7c021e7f55
```

I would have to convert the hex representation (2 char bytes) into the base64 representation. In nodejs, I try the following,

```
var hexBuffer = new Buffer('ce377789add2698f68d4cb7c021e7f55', 'hex');
var base64MD5String = hexBuffer.toString('base64'); // returns 'zjd3ia3SaY9o1Mt8Ah5/VQ=='
```

however, I get the bad digest error when passing the base64MD5String as the ContentMD5 parameter in AWS.S3.upload. What's wrong with the way I calculate/ encode the MD5?

Edit: I am using the Amazon example titled 'uploading an arbitrarily sized stream' however, I am already working with files that are tar'd and gzip'd so im not piping into zlib.

```
var fs = require('fs');

var body = fs.createReadStream('bigfile');
var s3obj = new AWS.S3({params: {Bucket: 'myBucket', Key: 'myKey'}});
s3obj.upload({Body: body}).
  on('httpUploadProgress', function(evt) { console.log(evt); }).
  send(function(err, data) { console.log(err, data) });
```

Comment: Assuming `ce377789add2698f68d4cb7c021e7f55` is indeed the correct md5sum of the file, then I can confirm that `zjd3ia3SaY9o1Mt8Ah5/VQ==` is the correct base64 encoding of the binary representation of that hash.  You didn't link to the specific amazon docs you're referencing, and I wasn't able to find it.  Please include that link, and mention how you're doing the upload -- are you writing your own code, or using the SDK?  Show some code, please?  Including -- how are you constructing the HTTP request?  Have you captured or dumped the raw http request to see what it looks like?

Comment: Also of interest, when you upload the file without specifying `Content-MD5:`, and then look at it in the console, what's the `ETag` shown?  Is the number of bytes correct, or too large or too small?  If you are gzipping the file and using `Content-Encoding: gzip` with the upload, then you need to take an md5 of the gzipped data, not the uncompressed payload.

Comment: Thanks! `ContentMD5: new Buffer(hash,'hex').toString('base64')` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Below what i did, it works fine.

```
var md5 = require('md5');
var hash = md5('test');

ContentMD5: new Buffer(hash,'hex').toString('base64');
```